# Solr "core" permissions

Tags: solr

Using Solr Basic auth plugin

How do you set permissions based on the "core"?  Only want certain users to be able to access a certain core.

I thought that was the "collection" value, but that isn't it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my own experience trying to solve this exact issue a year ago - I'm unable to find the reference where I read this, but:

You can't limit access to a specific core through `security.json` - if you need to limit which users can access which sets of data, you'll have to use SolrCloud and the `collections` parameter.

You might be able to limit access by having a reverse proxy in front, but be aware that certain GET parameters could be used to switch the request handler back in the "old days" - but that might have been removed now (and not sure if you could switch cores in the same way).

You also have to use the `path` parameter to limit operations (i.e. to only allow a user to access `/select` or `/replication` etc.).

Comment: Bummer, that's what I was starting to conclude, but just thought it was such a basic security feature, I couldn't accept that it was true! haha Thanks for the help.